# How to aquire CEF loaded resource URL？

Tags: html, url, resources, chromium-embedded

I am currently using chromium embedded framework with Delphi, I wanna know how to get the resource URL that the framework loaded during a visit. just like that firefox developer tool shows in "Network" tab .

Answer (score 0):

Use the TChromium.OnBeforeResourceLoad event and read the request.Url parameter